# URL gets appended when posting data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url

I do have a single field to enter `Date` information. When I hit `Submit` button, the URL gets appended with some additional stuff.

What I should get: `http://localhost:8080/employee/1`

What I get: `http://localhost:8080/employee/1?date=2018-02`

Clearly a `Date` appended to the URL. Any way to solve it?

My controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
public String showSpecificEmployee(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam(name = "date", required = false) String date, Model model){

    if(date == null)
        model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeById(new Long(id)));
    else
        model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeWithFilteredWorkdaysAndPayments(new Long(id), date));

    return "specificEmployee";
}
```

Comment: Submission is done by the client (browser). That's where (browser), I would look to see why it is doing the things it is doing to the URL -  not the request handling on the server. Look and show us if you need help, the form submission HTML and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the browser if the full URL of the current request. The presence of the `?` indicates that the browser has sent a `GET` request with the parameter `date` having the value `2018-02`.

As you speak of a `Submit` button, it means that the response to the previous request contained a `form` element. The type of the request is then determined by the `method` attribute of that `form` element and is by default a `GET`.

So you just need to change that `<form ...>` element to `<form ... method='POST'>`, because whereas a `GET` requests passes its parameter in the URL, a `POST` one passes them in its body.

Answer (score 1):

**Server side :** You need to specify the method action as a POST :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

**Client side :** if you use a `Form` or an `JS` request you have to specify the action methode as `POST` too.

Comment: Setting `method = RequestMethod.POST` in the `RequestMapping` annotation will not change the type of the request sent by the client, but will only restrain the controller method to POST requests.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Yes you are right, If you do not specify any mapping this method will resolve all the http request you can send (`GET, POST,   PUT, HEAD, DELETE ... `), in some cases you need to restrain the controller method to avoid some side effects. The main thing to do for reolve the issue is to check the client side.